# Can anyone help give a clear definition of what is a linear map restricted to a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand what is a linear map and what is a subspace and invariant subspace, but the lecture note I have does not give clear definition of what is a "linear map restricted to a subspace". Can anyone help give an explanation of this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $i: Y\subset X$ is the inclusion (i.e. $i(y) = y$ as an element of $X$) and $\phi:X\rightarrow Z$ the map, then the restriction of $\phi$ to $Y$ is defined by $\phi\circ i$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's very helpful. I added a supplement question, maybe you could help have a look when you have time.

Comment: @River I could but I won't. I answered the question in it's original version. I consider it bad practice (and unfair to everyone who cared to answer, which, in this case, includes me) to change a question which has already received answers in such a way that existing correct and complete answers become wrong or incomplete. If you have additional questions with regard to the topic just ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. I heed your advise. I am new here so forgive me for this time. I have restored the question to the original version and posted a new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2048701/a-further-help-required-for-what-is-a-linear-map-restricted-to-a-subspace